# Magento custom dependent category attributes

Tags: php, magento

I have some custom attributes for my project.

Attribute1 : Use in home page sidebar(yes/no)

if it is yes show the below attribute.

Attribute2 : Browse image

I want to add **attribute2** based on the **attribute1**. Only when the **Use in Home Page Sidebar** is enabled , my new attribute will be shown below of the current. I.e., it will be a dependent attribute. Does somebody know the script for adding dependent attributes in Magento?

Previously i added custom attributes by

```
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'use_home_page_side_bar', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'label'         => 'Use in Home Page Sidebar',
    'backend'       => '',
    'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Like this script, is there any script for adding dependent attributes?

Comment: You want the dependent attributes in backend or frontend ?

Comment: I want it in backend , for the categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on admin forms, then a class exists for automatically hiding elements when the value of fields change.

Below is an **example** which shows field dependency.

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form();

$form->addField('yesno', 'select', array(
    'label'  => $this->__('Yes or No?'),
    'values' => Mage::model('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesnocustom')
        ->toOptionArray(),
));

$form->addField('custom_value', text, array(
    'label'  => $this->__('Other'),
));


// Append dependency javascript
$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
        ->addFieldMap('yesno', 'yesno')
        ->addFieldMap('custom_value', 'custom_value')
        ->addFieldDependence('custom_value', 'yesno', 2) // 2 = 'Specified'
);
```

You need to map every field name to an element **ID**. You can add as many field mappings and field dependencies in this way as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I have created simple category attribute dependency by adding new input renderer for attribute. It is working this way:
You have several attributes:

```
– my_attribute
– my_attribute_text
– my_attribute_select
```

Note that they all start from **my_attribute**.

First attribute has boolean type. When it is set to true – other attributes that start from **my_attribute** is visible.

Source - https://github.com/elpas0/category_dependence

Description - http://nwdthemes.com/2015/02/20/magento-category-attributes-dependency/